# How to extract .txt file from .gz files using 7zip using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, gzip, 7zip, text-extraction

The code works without error and opens the application 7zip with folder but does not extract the text file.

```
Sub B_UnZip_Zip_File_Fixed()

    Dim PathZipProgram As String, NameUnZipFolder As String
    Dim FileNameZip As Variant, ShellStr As String
    PathZipProgram = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip"
    If Right(PathZipProgram, 1) <> "\" Then
        PathZipProgram = PathZipProgram & "\"
    End If
    If Dir(PathZipProgram & "7zFM.exe") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please find your copy of 7z.exe and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    NameUnZipFolder = "C:\vba\"
    FileNameZip = "C:\vba\zout.Gz"
    Shell (PathZipProgram & "7zFM.exe e -aoa" _
             & " " & Chr(34) & FileNameZip & Chr(34) _
             & " -o" & " " & Chr(34) & NameUnZipFolder & "*.txt*")
    MsgBox "Look in " & NameUnZipFolder & " for extracted files"

End Sub
```

I used Shell Script, but it doesn't extract the file.

Comment: See [VBA code to Zip and Unzip files and folders](https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-cod-to-zip-unzip/).

Comment: Thank you RoberBaron, it works for Zip file, but i need to extract files from .GZ format

Comment: I see. Then you need the standalone version of 7-zip, that is [7za.exe](http://originaldll.com/file/7za.exe/24132.html).

Comment: Could ypu please help me with some coding, i have 7za.exe downloaded it , same code works her but no output

Comment: This link works for 7Zip https://www.7-zip.org/download.html